Need help nesting multiple =IF into one formula?
For the life of me i cannot figure out how to add mulitple conditions into this formula can anyone help? here is what i am working with.
=IF(regexmatch(F43,"MILLING"),"RND / MILLING ","RND / ORDER",=IF(regexmatch(F43,"PROFILING"),"RND / PROFILING ","RND / ORDER")
Im not sure how to string mutliple into the same forumla

The syntax is
=if(condition, do when true, do when false)
You can chain several conditions
= if(condition1, 
      do when true, 
      if(condition2, 
           do when true, 
           do when false
      )
)

The indentation is not required, but it illustrates what belongs together.
So, applied to your formula, that would be
=IF(regexmatch(F43,"MILLING"),
     "RND / MILLING ",
     IF(regexmatch(F43,"PROFILING"),
         "RND / PROFILING ",
         "RND / ORDER"
     )
)


Use ifs() to test multiple conditions, like this:
=ifs( 
  isblank(F43), iferror(ø), 
  regexmatch(F43, "MILLING"), "RND / MILLING", 
  regexmatch(F43, "PROFILING"), "RND / PROFILING", 
  regexmatch(F43, "ORDER"), "RND / ORDER", 
  true, "RND / ORDER" 
)

In the above, the last condition is set to true so that it catches any value.
See ifs().
